# Meteor APK shows white screen, nothing happens

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, apk

The app works fine in a browser, and in dev mode (i.e., with "meteor run android-device").  But when I build and install the APK, I see the splash screen (Meteor logo), followed by a white page.

Is there some way to see console.log output on an Android device?  Any other way to debug this behavior?  logcat shows nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chrome remote debugging tool to see the console outputs.

Read here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had the wrong server configured in my build.  My fault.  Still... it would be nice to have some way to debug this, rather than guessing my way through it.